# How to protect my 3d model file（gltf）？

Tags: three.js, gltf

I used a threejs to write a game and used a lot of gltf files. I don't want to expose these gltf files directly.

Comment: You can't really. You could try to encrypt or zip then but a determined person can just lift them out of memory, same as any other game tech.

Comment: Welcome to the web - everything you do is visible and technically stealable. Just be proud of your work, own it, and let the thieves be thieves - nothing to win there.

Comment: @manthrax Ok! I am too naive! So what are the proven schemes for encryption or compression? If not, I have to toss it again.

Comment: There's https://github.com/Stuk/jszip which I have used before. Seems to work pretty well. You'll have to decompress into memory and use the GLTFLoader().parse( method I think...  R.E. Encryption I don't really know.. but implementations exist.. But be aware that all of your textures+meshes will still be visible using a GPU inspecting tool like WebGLInspector...

Comment: @manthrax thank you for your help. Looks good!

Answer (score 0):

For the record, this cannot be done. Obfuscation can get you really far and deter a casual hacker, but all graphics data can be intercepted and extracted since it has to be made available and formatted properly for drawing.